# httpsession lifecycle events not working after using my custom UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, session-cookies, session-timeout

I've created my own UserDetailsService and UserDetails implementations and hooked it up. I can create users, and login as users. However, if I login, logout, and then login again, I'm getting a redirect to a timeout error page. This is because I'm preventing concurrent logins, but it's not working - it used to with the "hello world" auth examples, but now with my own implementations that piece has stopped working correctly for some reason. Spring basically thinks there are 2 sessions when I login, logout, and login again.

Now - I thought this was all handled automatically ....perhaps using your own UserDetailsService means you actually have to implement session management somewhere else as well? I'm sort of blown away that's not mentioned in the docs or in the book Spring Security 3.1 so I'm assuming I'm missing something.

This is in my web.xml  bit for listening to session life cycle events

```
<!-- This listener updates spring-security on httpsession lifecycle events, 
in this case to ensure each user can have only 1 session at a time. -->
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and this is in my security.xml  to prevent concurrent logins

```
<!-- This prevents the user from logging in more than once simultaneously -->
<security:session-management
invalid-session-url="/timeout.htm">
<security:concurrency-control
max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</security:session-management>
```

My logout in the security context file is

```
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout"
        invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"
        logout-success-url="/login.htm?logout" />
```

I've tried a few permutations of that. None seem to work. invalidate-session="true" is the default value, so I shouldn't even have to specify this. But it doesn't seem to be happening.

O.k., I just reverted everything to try and do in-memory auth and I'm getting the same errors. Meaning, I'm not using my custom implementations anymore. Sorry - I clearly have something wrong somewhere...and this is proving extremely difficult to find. I might have to start from scratch.

Do I have to do something special on logout with my custom UserDetailsService?

Any feedback or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it was a conflict between using `<session-management>` in my configuration and my servlet container. I'm using STS 3.5 (custom Eclipse for Spring projects) with vFabric server that runs in the IDE. The [Reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#session-mgmt) did not refer to this in the actual Session Management section (Section 8). However, buried in Section 4 on auth is this little gem:

> Note that if you use this mechanism to detect session timeouts, it may falsely report an error if the user logs out and then logs back in without closing the browser. This is because the session cookie is not cleared when you invalidate the session and will be resubmitted even if the user has logged out. You may be able to explicitly delete the JSESSIONID cookie on logging out, for example by using the following syntax in the logout handler:

```
<http>
  <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

> Unfortunately this can’t be guaranteed to work with every servlet container, so you will need to test it in your environment

Well, apparently it doesn't work in STS 3.5

At first I tried to eliminate sections of my `<session-management>` tag so I could just control concurrency (i.e. have the user only able to log in with one session at a time). However, I just kept getting errors.

So, at this point I've removed the session management stuff altogether and will come back to it when ready to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding the `error-if-maximum-exceeded` attribute should be `false`. Settings the value to `false` will cause the original session to expire instead of throwing a exception as explained in http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#d0e7768

Comment: Well, problem is it worked before I used my own UserDetailsService and just used the Spring one. If I logged out and then log back in there should only be one session, right? I should only get an error if there's more than one session, correct? So I think the actual problem is that for some reason when I hit logout it is not actually loggin me out, or clearing the current user / session stuff. I thought Spring did that automatically, so now I have to figure out why it's not - how does using my own UserDetailsService break that - or is that something I have to account for now.

Comment: Can you add the UserDetailService and the logout configuration to your question?

Comment: O.k., I added the session management stuff in web.xml and security.xml to the tutorial code from the book Spring Security 3.1 This code ran fine before I did it. Just adding that xml which I've posted above broke it - same error. So, somehow it's in how I'm specifying session management in that xml. But, I lifted that off of the reference docs, that's how they say to do it. So...

Comment: Just found this footnote: "Authentication by mechanisms which perform a redirect after authenticating (such as form-login) will not be detected by`SessionManagementFilter`, as the filter will not be invoked during the authenticating request. Session-management functionality has to be handled separately in these cases." Hilareously, form-login is used in all of the examples. And there doesn't seem to be any link as to how to handle this separately. Perhaps I'm totally overlooking something super simple here? I could just not specify this stuff, but then what is doing session management?

Comment: Thanks Bart very much for trying to help. I discovered it was my servlet container - using STS 3.5 (custom Eclipse for Spring projects) with vFabric server that runs in the IDE. That apparently invalidates the cached authentication but doesn't clear it out unless you close the browser and open it again. The result is the very specific behavior that you can't login, logout, and login again. So, for now I've just taken out my session management directives. I'll come back to it later before deployment - and evaluate it within the actual environment I'll be using for deployment.